# Match nearest earlier timestamp in R

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have the following:

```
dates1 <-  as.POSIXct(c("2015-10-26 12:00:00","2015-10-26 13:00:00","2015-10-26 14:00:00"))
values1 <- c("a","b","c")

dates2 <- as.POSIXct(c("2015-10-26 11:59:00","2015-10-26 12:00:10"))
values2 <- c("A","C")

df1 <- data.frame(dates1, values1)
df2 <- data.frame(dates2, values2)
```

I want to merge values2 from df2 into df1, where I want to select the nearest timestamp in df2 BEFORE the timestamp in df1. For example, for 12:00:00, I want to select 11:59:00, and not 12:00:10 (which is the nearest, but not the nearest before 12:00:00). My expected output is:

```
                dates1 values2 values1   dates2
1: 2015-10-26 12:00:00       A       a   2015-10-26 11:59:00
2: 2015-10-26 13:00:00       c       b   2015-10-26 12:00:10
3: 2015-10-26 14:00:00       c       c   2015-10-26 12:00:10
```

using the roll = "nearest" option from data.table, does not yield the expected outcome. Can anyone help me?

using the roll = "nearest" option from data.table, does not yield the expected outcome

Comment: `df1[df2, c("values2", "dates2") := .(i.values2, i.dates2), on = .(dates1 >= dates2)]` works without `roll=`, is that enough?

Comment: @r2evans Maybe elevate the comment to a question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `dplyr::join_by()` and `dplyr::closest()`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  left_join(
    df2,
    join_by(
      closest(y$dates2 <= x$dates1)
    )
  )
#>                dates1 values1              dates2 values2
#> 1 2015-10-26 12:00:00       a 2015-10-26 11:59:00       A
#> 2 2015-10-26 13:00:00       b 2015-10-26 12:00:10       C
#> 3 2015-10-26 14:00:00       c 2015-10-26 12:00:10       C
```

Comment: With all due respect this question was a) tagged `data.table` and b) `data.table` has had those rolling since "forever".  Your answer is off-topic.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, Sorry.  Just trying to help.

Comment: No worries, I have also fired off less than ideal answers on this site. Consider deleting this answer, I am sure you get to show off your `dplyr` skills on another question soon.

Comment: I disagree that this is perfectly off-topic: yes, tagged, but ... no use of `data.table` or `setDT`, so it is possible that the user feels it must be `data.table` but other tricks might exist. I've often seen [tag:data.table], [tag:datatable], and [tag:data.frame] tags used interchangeably (and incorrectly). Yes, the OP asked for `data.table`, but sometimes a working solution (in base R or dplyr or something else) is sufficient. I think when it's this close, it may be sufficient for the OP to choose to accept or not that marks it as perfectly appropriate.

Comment: Hi Josh, thank you for your time and effort to answer my question. It does yield the expected outcome, and I consider it as "a correct" answer. My first thought, when I wanted to tackle it, was to use data.table. I now learned that dplyr was also possible.

Comment: It's a super-common operation when dealing with financial times series, and that is actually where `data.table` was born too.  So it had this since "forever", and many of us have taken advantage of for many years.  OP decides, and if it is an accepted my criticism is clearly overriden.  I maintain _that given the existing tag_ it was a wee bit off to suggest an answer with a different toolchain.  But heck, I am sure someone will volunteer a pandas or polars solution next <wink>

Comment: Written more compactly it is even shorter:  `left_join(df1, df2, join_by(closest(y$dates2 <= x$dates1)))`  (as you're not forced to use either `%>%` or `|>`).